# dotnet core 2.0 mvc publish issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I use areas in my dotnet core 2.0 mvc project, in debug and release mode it can find the views of areas, but when I published this project and deploied it in the iis,it was prompt that the view was not found.

I read the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?tabs=aspnetcore2x),and then I set the **MvcRazorCompileOnPublish** to **false**,but it has no use.

I separated the Controllers to a class lib and the mvc project dependency the Controllers class lib.

This project's github repositories address is https://github.com/Lanesra712/Danvic.PSU

Here is my code ,how can I do it to fix this bug,thanks!

```
//Startup.cs

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Secret}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areas",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

//Program.cs

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

//Danvic.PSU.csproj

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Here is I deploied it in the iis and prompt info and project pic.

[the project frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIBMT.png)

[the prompt info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yS8g.png)